# I want to convert byte[] into float, but just the first 4 numbers are correct

Tags: java, byte, converters

So I am saving an audio file. And i have to convert `float[]` to `byte[]`. This works fine:

```
 final byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[buffer.length * 2];
        int bufferIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < byteBuffer.length; i++) {
            final int x = (int) (buffer[bufferIndex++] * 32767.0);
            byteBuffer[i] = (byte) x;
            i++;
            byteBuffer[i] = (byte) (x >>> 8);
            if (bufferIndex < 5) {
                System.out.println(buffer[bufferIndex]);
                System.out.println(byteBuffer[i - 1]);
                System.out.println(byteBuffer[i]);
            }

        }
```

But when i want to read the bytes and convert it back to floats just the first 4 numbers match with the old ones:

```
for (int i =0; i < length; i++) {

            i++;
            float val = (((audioB[i]) & 0xff) << 8) | ((audioB[i-1]) & 0xff);
            val = (float) (val /32767.0);
            if (bufferindex < 5) {
                System.out.println(val);
                System.out.println(audioB[i-1]);
                System.out.println(audioB[i]);
            }
            bufferindex++;
        }
```

The output :

```
0.07973075
0
0
0.149165
52
10
0.19944257
23
19
0.22437502
-121
25

---------

0.0
0
0
0.07971435
52
10
0.14914395
23
19
0.19943845
-121
25
0.22437209
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stuffing 4 byte float data into just 2 bytes per sample. This will obviously loose some precisition. Hint: Do the backwards calculation (2 byte -> float) in your first loop and compare the result with the original value, and look at intermediate values like `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than implementing your own bit shifting magic, why not use the [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class?

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putFloat(1.0F).putFloat(2.0F).array();

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
float f1 = bb.getFloat();
float f2 = bb.getFloat();
```

Comment: Everything is explained in the javadoc. The link is in my answer.